# console commands help: can't progress in quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I used the command: setstage mq105 200, which completes the greybeards quest, then I got the next quest, horn of jurgen windcaller quest, I did the same and now I can't progress, the only active quest is the greybeards one but if I speak to them nothing happens. What should I do?

EDIT: I've figured it out, I had to setstage to 10, then 160 (which is the correct stage) then the whole town of riverwood was agressive to me, but I went to whiterun and paid the bounty and then I was able to continue.

Comment: Reload an older save data.

Answer (score 1):

You screwed up your game.  Couple problems here...

[Quest details for mq105](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Way_of_the_Voice#Quest_Stages)

Stage 200 isn't even a valid stage.  Stage 160 is the final stage.  I don't know what happens if you set your quest to an invalid stage.

[Quest Details for "The Horn of Jurgen Windcaller"](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Horn_of_Jurgen_Windcaller#Quest_Stages)

This quest is suppose to teach you two shouts.  By using the console to complete the quest, there is no easy way to determine what you are missing, and whether any future quests are broken.  You are most likely missing a key shout (Whirlwind Sprint) so you'll not be able to complete parts of some quests unless you hunt for the 2nd and 3rd word.

Bottom line.  Don't skip quests like this, ESPECIALLY for the main story.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the inn in Riverwood and see if you can reserve the attic room or what not.. You dont actually get the horn out of the dungeon you were to go to you get it from the inn keeper there.. That may set your quests back to being able to go forward.

Otherwise, save, save often and reload when you need to.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The part with meeting Delphine is in the middle of the horn of jurgen windcaller quest, stage 20.

Answer (score 0):

I messed up this quest and got a Failed Quest tag ... but then I went out to The Inn at Riverwood and paid Delphine 10 gold to stay in the attic room ... some how this kicked the quest back in gear and she started asking the correct questions ... I was then able to kill the dragon with her, got the Horn and continued on with the quest chain